# Как исправить фон боковой панели

Tags: html, bootstrap

Имеется вот такая боковая панель:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно она не вытянута во всю высоту страницы.

Но если рядом вставить любой текст то она начет вытягиваться вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это исправить, чтобы панель всегда была во всю высоту?

Вот мой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Resume</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-bg-dark bg-gradient" style="width: 280px;">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="40" height="32"></use></svg>
        <span class="fs-4">Resume</span>
      </a>
      <hr>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
            <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"></use></svg><span>  Home  </span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"></use></svg><span>  Education  </span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"></use></svg><span>  Skils  </span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <h3 align="center" style="color:Black">info</h3>
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis
        leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc
      </h5>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо для `.row` добавить `.min-vh-100`

Пример

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Resume</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row min-vh-100">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-bg-dark bg-gradient" style="width: 280px;">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="40" height="32"></use></svg>
        <span class="fs-4">Resume</span>
      </a>
      <hr>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
            <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"></use></svg><span>  Home  </span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"></use></svg><span>  Education  </span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"></use></svg><span>  Skils  </span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr class="mt-auto">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <h3 align="center" style="color:Black">info</h3>
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras
        dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
        laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque
        sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis
        leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc
      </h5>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо это помогло, а можно спросить как теперь переместить линию от тега <hr> вниз боковой панели?

Comment: @Manifesto Mr - там два тега hr, какой из них?

Comment: Нужно сместить тег hr, который находится внизу...

Comment: @Manifesto Mr - обновил